# Determining independence (dependence) normal random variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis, random-variable

I've the following question which I'm struggling to **deduce** **independence** (**for part b and c**) based on theorems given in the class for the multivariate normal distribution. I've the theorems, and managed to solve a) checking the covariance of variables i.e x3 with all variables in second vector, and x6 with all variable in second vector = 0.

[image: Normal Random variables]

Here some theorems from class (emailed professor too, who hinted at using these for part b and c)

**theorem 4.3.1**

[image: 4.3.1 theorem]

**theorem 4.3.3**

[image: 4.3.3 theorem]

**theorem 4.3.4**

[image: 4.3.4 theorem]

**theorem 4.3.5**
[image: 4.3.5 theorem]

Please let me know any hints for part b) and c).

Thanks.

Comment: Hint for (b), and (c) is similar: Can you find $\mathrm{Cov}(X_1+X_4,X_2+X_5)$?  This is $\mathrm{Cov}(X_1,X_2)+\mathrm{Cov}(X_1,X_5)+\mathrm{Cov}(X_4,X_2)+\mathrm{Cov}(X_4,X_5)$

Comment: I see this is an identity (more of a distributive law)... can you please link any page of such idenities. Also what about constants in front of the variables e.g 4X3 ... do we bring that in front of the Cov expression ?

Comment: Covariance is [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Relationship_to_inner_products)

Comment: thank you very much for your help